# How replace a node term programmatically?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary (this is a workflow vocabulary) and another vocabulary attach to a node.

How can I replace workflow term by single another workflow term without change some other vocabulary ?

Something like this ?

```
$old_terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, 23);
foreach($old_terms as $tid => $old_term){
  unset($node->taxonomy[$tid]);
}
$new_term = taxonomy_get_term(30);
$node->taxonomy[$new_term->tid] = $new_term;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add term using term id(tid) `$node->field_yourfield_name[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $tid` in D7

Answer (score 0):

To get the node:

```
$node = node_load($X); // $X is the node ID.
```

To attache a term ID - note that this is very different in D7:

```
$node->taxonomy[$tid] = taxonomy_get_term($tid); // $tid is the node ID.
```

To save the node - if the node is new:

```
node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

or, to save the node if it's an existing node:

```
node_save($node);
```

---

In Drupal 7, terms are attached as normal field items so field_first_name[0] means the first occurrence of the field. Don't confuse that functionality with terms. You can add as many as terms you want.

Comment: your are right to add a new term but if you already have attached the term to your node, how do you replace it ? I am looking for the best practice ?